# Looking for First Year Statistics Lecture Notes

Tags: online-resources

I'm looking for lecture notes for a first course of statistics. When I tried looking for lecture notes myself they were either not comprehensive or too advanced for my level.

Does anybody know of a good resource I can use?

Answer (score 1):

[Openstax Intro to Statistics](https://openstax.org/details/books/introductory-statistics) is the best of its kind, not only because it is free but because it is written by the top stats professors of American Universities.

I also used Gilbert Strang's Calc IV book on the same (free and open source) series. If I could learn Stats again, it would be through this.